# Download file right away?

Tags: html

how can I make a PDF file download automatically when someones click on my link? I mean when someone will open an email there will be a link to download a PDF guide and I would like it to automatically download when they click on that link without needing to click any download buttons or whatever.

Comment: Just link to the pdf immediately. Depending on the browser it will open the file or prompt the user to open or download it

Comment: I have it uploaded straight to my domain name and when I visit website I get that regular "index of" page with PDF below which I can open but I would like to make it download automatically

Comment: That is what i just explained. Link to the pdf not your website.
Micheal Karpinski even made an answer with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="/file-location.pdf" download>Download</a>`